# In react redux-toolkit, how to deal browsers console error in axios api bad-requests response

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, axios, interceptor, redux-toolkit

I have created a file named api.js. The code is below-

```
import axios from "axios";

const API=axios.create({
    baseURL:"http://localhost:4000",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/form-data"}
});
//authentication & user
export const loginUserApi=(formData)=>API.post(`/api/v1/login`,formData);
```

and below is my auth slice file where I just import this api file to fetch data and store state value. My code is -

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import * as api from "../api";

export const login= createAsyncThunk("auth/login", async({formData},{rejectWithValue})=>{
    try{
        const { data } = await api.loginUserApi(formData);        
        return data.user;
    }catch(error){
        return rejectWithValue(error.response.data.message);
    }
})
const authSlice=createSlice({
    name:"auth",
    initialState:{},
    reducers:{},
    extraReducers:{
        //user login
        [login.pending]:(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=true;
        },
        [login.fulfilled]:(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.user=action.payload;    
        },
        [login.rejected]:(state,action)=>{
            state.loading=false;
            state.error=action.payload;       
        },
    }
});
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I can store user data or show error to client from my error state. But what I found the problem is - if I make an error to fetch the api, the browsers console also show the error in red color, like 400 bad request... etc. Is axios interceptors can deal with that? Then how to setup? I want the error message in state not in browsers console.

I used try, catch, finally block but didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Many browsers will log the error in the console. You can't change that.

Also, handling the error doesn't stop it from being visible in the error tab. I doubt if your users would want to always open the network tab to check what's wrong.